# What options do I have to protect an online page/directory?

Tags: http, .htaccess, authentication

I am working with some online apps that have a members area, so I obviously need to restrict access to some pages/directories only to members.

So far I have seen two methods to restrict access to specific pages/directories:

1. HTTP authentication
2. .htaccess

**Questions**:
1. Are there other methods?
2. What's the industry standard these days? For instance, what does Facebook or Google use to protect the sections of their websites that only registered users can access?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It really depends on the architecture of the online app. You could also handle authentication in your scripts (PHP for example) and serve everything member specific from external directories.

For example, you could have the following directory tree:

```
/
|
+---FilesForMembers
|
+---httproot
```

You could store all member specific files in `FilesForMembers` and create a script in `httproot` that can serve files from `FilesForMembers`.

That way the member specific files would be out of reach for the web server.

Comment: But how would the directory be protected? It would have a PHP script requiring a session ID for each user?

Comment: The directory wouldn't need to be protected. As it is outside the root directory of the web server, the web server won't serve anything from that directory. The script would be responsible for making sure that no user can access files or data that don't belong to him.